# How to force deploy to lambda via SAM cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am using `sam deploy` command to deploy my lambda to AWS. Sometimes I get this error `An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Stack:arn:aws:cloudformation:ap-southeast-2:xxxx:stack/xxxx/xxxx is in ROLLBACK_COMPLETE state and can not be updated.` I know there is a failure happens on the previous deployment. I can manually delete the stack in AWS cloundformation console and retry the command. But I wonder is there is way to force the command to delete any rollback state stack?

I know I can delete the failed stack via aws cli or console. But my `deploy` script is on CI and I'd like to make CI to use `deploy` command to override the failed stack. So the scenario is:

```
1. CI failed on deploy lambda function
2. My team analysis the issue and fix the issue in cloudformation template file
3. Push the fix to github to tigger the CI
4. CI is triggered and use the latest change to override the failed stack.
```

I don't want the team to manually delete the stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ROLLBACK_COMPLETE` status exists only after a failed stack **creation**. The only option is to delete the stack. This is to give you a chance to correctly analyze the reason behind the failure.

You can delete the stack from the command line with:

```
aws cloudformation delete-stack --stack-name <value>
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-describing-stacks.html) of `ROLLBACK_COMPLETE`:

> Successful removal of one or more stacks after a failed stack creation or after an explicitly canceled stack creation. Any resources that were created during the create stack action are deleted.
>
> This status exists only after a failed stack creation. It signifies that all operations from the partially created stack have been appropriately cleaned up. When in this state, only a delete operation can be performed.

Normally the `ROLLBACK_COMPLETE` should not happen in production. I would suggest validating your stack in a development environment or have one successful stack creation in your production environment before continuously deploying your stack.

Still, you could have a custom script in your CI that checks the stack status ([DescribeStacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeStacks.html)) and if it's `ROLLBACK_COMPLETE` delete it ([DeleteStack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_DeleteStack.html)). This script would run before `sam deploy`.

Comment: I know I can delete the stack via command or aws console. But the deploy command is written in CI and is there a way for CI to use `deploy` command to force delete the failed stack?

Comment: FYI there is now a `sam delete` command: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-delete.html